# Add consecutive numbers to a certain string in a text file (pairwise the same number)

Tags: text-processing, command-line

How can I add consecutive numbers to a string in a text file, with two strings each having the same number?

example:

```
id="picture-"
id="picture-"
id="picture-"
id="picture-"
...
```

result:

```
id="picture-1"
id="picture-1"
id="picture-2"
id="picture-2"
...
```

The number is not at the last position in the lines.
I have tried this:

```
perl -pe 's/picture\-/$& . ++$n/ge' index.txt
```

But this adds the numbers so, that every string gets another number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this part of an HTML or XML file, by chance?

Comment: Yes it is a part of an HTML file.

Comment: So, there's a lot of _other_ data in the file that should _not_ be modified?

Comment: What if one of the "id" portions is HTML-commented-out?

Comment: What if you have elements with names like `zoid=foo` or `acid=base`? What if you have "picture" text that's elsewhere? Would it - should it - throw off the numbering?

Comment: @Kusalananda – I understand. Since you use `"` as delimiter, the command also finds other strings, which would actually be a problem because the quotation marks are common in the file.

Comment: @elli As far as _we_ know, you are showing your _complete_ file.  We don't know if you have more data in your file and can therefore not give you a robust solution.

Comment: You should use each id only once in a HTML document. If you need it for styling, use a CSS class instead.

Comment: Don't try to parse or modify HTML with regular expressions alone.  Use a HTML parser.  e.g. perl's [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser) module (or [HTML::SimpleParse](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::SimpleParse), or one of several other alternatives).   These are very commonly used and are probably available as packages for your distribution if you're running Linux (they certainly are on debian and debian derivatives).

Answer (score 1):

You can always do:

```
perl -pe 's/picture-\K/1+($n++>>1)/ge' index.txt
```

To generate the data from scratch:

```
seq -f 'id="picture-%.0f"' 10 | sed p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F '"' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS; n=1 } { $2 = sprintf("%s%d", $2, ++n/2); print }' file
id="picture-1"
id="picture-1"
id="picture-2"
id="picture-2"
```

Here, we treat each line as a set of `"`-delimited fields.  The second field is modified by `awk` by adding an integer to the end of it.  The integer is incremented by one for each line, but also divided by two.  The effect is that the number in the output would be incremented by one every second line (due to rounding when the number is used with the `%d` format in `sprintf()`).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for loop.

Assumptions:

- You know the maximum number of entries to create.
- The prefix is constant.
- Your output is simply "prefix-number".

```
#!/bin/sh

# Define constants
prefix="picture-"
max_count=30

# For/Next style loop
for i in ((i=1;i<=$max_count;i++))
do
    echo "${prefix}${i}"
end
```

Comment: It's not elegant, but it works and is simple to understand & modify. I like to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

A slight alteration to your `perl` one-liner:

```
perl -mPOSIX -pe 's/picture\-/$& . POSIX::ceil(++$n\/2)/ge' index.txt
```

The number appended is now half-n, rounded up, so the result only increases every other line.